# Store tree structured data to an array in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree

I am trying to write a code to transverse a tree data structure using inorder transversal and store all the nodes onto an array.

I came up with this code below but it doesn't work, as the index of any previous recursion has already been passed on in the function.

```
int *inorderTransversal(AVLTreeNode *node, AVLTreeNode *array[], int index)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return index;

    inorderTransversal(node->left, array, index);
    nodesArray[index] = node;
    index++;
    inorderTransversal(node->right, array, index);
    return index; 
}
```

I know I could possibly declare a static 'index' value inside the function, and it might work? But the downside is it makes 'index' stays in the memory for the entire duration of the program e.g.

```
void *inorderTransversal(AVLTreeNode *node, AVLTreeNode *array[])
{
    static int index = 0;
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    inorderTransversal(node->left, array);
    nodesArray[index] = node;
    index++;
    inorderTransversal(node->right, array);
    return; 
}
```

Or I could declare the index outside the function prior? e.g.

```
AVLTreeNode *array[tree->size]; 
int index = 0; 

void *inorderTransversal(AVLTreeNode *node) { 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 

    inorderTransversal(node->left); 
    array[index] = node; 
    index++;
    inorderTransversal(node->right); 
}
```

Could someone help me to amend the code to include the 'index' increments inside the function without using static? Much appreciated!

Comment: You *must* declare the array outside the function (and before calling it). How else were you planning to call it?

Comment: I wanted to say 'index'..

Comment: Why do you return `index` (which is an `int`) if you have defined the function to return an `int *` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was close.  You want to pass in `index` as an `int *`.  Then you can dereference it and update it.

```
void inorderTransversal(AVLTreeNode *node, AVLTreeNode *array[], int *index)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    inorderTransversal(node->left, treeSize, index);
    nodesArray[*index] = node;
    (*index)++;
    inorderTransversal(node->right, treeSize, index);
}
```

When you call this function, you pass the address of an `int` which has been initialized to 0.  When the recursion ends it will hold the number of elements in the list.

Comment: You are my lighthouse on the sea!

Comment: @BobbyLi Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.